# externalize pfgplots fails with shell escape enabled (TexLive-2013 Mac)

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-external, shell-escape, matlab2tikz

I have the following Problem: I am using matlab2tikz to get my Matlab plots into latex. I have very large time series, that i already cut down using resampling. Nevertheless my I need a lot more time to compile my Latex. I read about using `\externalize` to save the figure once compiled.
In my header file (separate tex. document to have better overview) use:

```
 \usepackage{pgfplots}
 \pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
```

with that I tried the following three options:

1.

```
\usetikzlibrary{external} 
\tikzexternalize[prefix=autofigs/]
```

2.

```
\usetikzlibrary{external} \tikzset{external/system call={lualatex
     \tikzexternalcheckshellescape -halt-on-error
     -interaction=batchmode -jobname "\image" "\texsource"}}
 \tikzexternalize[prefix=autofigs/]
```

3.

```
\usetikzlibrary{external}
\tikzset{external/system call={latex \tikzexternalcheckshellescape -halt-on-error
-interaction=batchmode -jobname "\image" "\texsource";
dvips -o "\image".ps "\image".dvi;
ps2eps "\image.ps"}}
\tikzexternalize
```

In my TexStudio 2.7.0 I set under preferences->commands

latex:

```
/usr/texbin/latex --shell-escape -src -interaction=nonstopmode  %.tex
```

pdfLaTeX

```
/usr/texbin/pdflatex --shell-escape -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode %.tex
```

LuaLaTeX

```
/usr/texbin/lualatex --shell-escape -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode %.tex
```

I should add that I don't really know what I am doing with those other than "enable shell escape"

Just to test this I copied a minimal example from somewhere in this forum:

```
\begin{tikzpicture} 
\draw[thick,blue] (2cm,0) -- (0:1cm) -- (90:1cm); 
\end{tikzpicture}
```

When I do compile&show (F1) I get the tike picture rendered but the following error message:

```
! Package tikz Error: Sorry, the system call 'lualatex -shell-escape -halt-on-e
rror -interaction=batchmode -jobname "autofigs/DA-figure0" "\def\tikzexternalre
aljob{DA}\input{DA}"' did NOT result in a usable output file 'autofigs/DA-figur
e0' (expected one of .pdf:.jpg:.jpeg:.png:). Please verify that you have enable
d system calls. For pdflatex, this is 'pdflatex -shell-escape'. Sometimes it is
 also named 'write 18' or something like that. Or maybe the command simply fail
ed? Error messages can be found in 'autofigs/DA-figure0.log'. If you continue n
ow, I'll try to typeset the picture.
```

It seems to have something to do with the system call not beeing executed (I don't get a new log-file in my tex folder)

edit: here is a minimal setup to showcase my problem:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,twoside]{report}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

\newlength\figureheight
\newlength\figurewidth 


\usetikzlibrary{external} 
\tikzexternalize[prefix=tikz/]


\begin{document}

      \tikzsetnextfilename{TESTOR}
      \begin{tikzpicture} 
      \draw[thick,blue] (2cm,0) -- (0:1cm) -- (90:1cm); 
      \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

What am i doing wrong ??
I really like the possibilities with this matlab2tikz workflow but those compiling times are just not tolerable....

thanks a bunch

edit:

running without nonstop mode by entering the following to pdflatex:

```
/usr/texbin/pdflatex -shell-escape -synctex=1  %.tex
```

(also tried two dashes in front of the shell...didnt change anything)

results in the Message:

```
/usr/texbin/pdflatex -shell-escape -synctex=1  %.tex
```

did i mess up the syntax somewhere ? Its not really an error message but there is nothing in my folder i set up for the "Prerendered" stuff to go in (autofigs)

here the log:

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.1415926-2.5-1.40.14 (TeX Live 2013) (format=pdflatex 2014.5.3)  22 MAY 2014 09:50
entering extended mode
 \write18 enabled.
 %&-line parsing enabled.
**Minimalbeispiel.tex
(./Minimalbeispiel.tex
LaTeX2e <2011/06/27>
Babel <3.9f> and hyphenation patterns for 78 languages loaded.
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/report.cls
Document Class: report 2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size12.clo
File: size12.clo 2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX file (size option)
)
\c@part=\count79
\c@chapter=\count80
\c@section=\count81
\c@subsection=\count82
\c@subsubsection=\count83
\c@paragraph=\count84
\c@subparagraph=\count85
\c@figure=\count86
\c@table=\count87
\abovecaptionskip=\skip41
\belowcaptionskip=\skip42
\bibindent=\dimen102
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgfplots/pgfplots.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgfplots/pgfplots.revision.tex)
Package: pgfplots 2013/03/17 v1.8 Data Visualization (1.8-3-gaf58a29)
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/basiclayer/pgf.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/utilities/pgfrcs.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfutil-common.te
x
\pgfutil@everybye=\toks14
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfutil-latex.def
\pgfutil@abb=\box26
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/ms/everyshi.sty
Package: everyshi 2001/05/15 v3.00 EveryShipout Package (MS)
))
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfrcs.code.tex
Package: pgfrcs 2010/10/25 v2.10 (rcs-revision 1.24)
))
Package: pgf 2008/01/15 v2.10 (rcs-revision 1.12)
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcore.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/graphicx.sty
Package: graphicx 1999/02/16 v1.0f Enhanced LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)

(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/keyval.sty
Package: keyval 1999/03/16 v1.13 key=value parser (DPC)
\KV@toks@=\toks15
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/graphics.sty
Package: graphics 2009/02/05 v1.0o Standard LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)

(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/trig.sty
Package: trig 1999/03/16 v1.09 sin cos tan (DPC)
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/latexconfig/graphics.cfg
File: graphics.cfg 2010/04/23 v1.9 graphics configuration of TeX Live
)
Package graphics Info: Driver file: pdftex.def on input line 91.

(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pdftex-def/pdftex.def
File: pdftex.def 2011/05/27 v0.06d Graphics/color for pdfTeX

(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/infwarerr.sty
Package: infwarerr 2010/04/08 v1.3 Providing info/warning/error messages (HO)
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/ltxcmds.sty
Package: ltxcmds 2011/11/09 v1.22 LaTeX kernel commands for general use (HO)
)
\Gread@gobject=\count88
))
\Gin@req@height=\dimen103
\Gin@req@width=\dimen104
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsys.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsys.code.tex
Package: pgfsys 2010/06/30 v2.10 (rcs-revision 1.37)
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfkeys.code.tex
\pgfkeys@pathtoks=\toks16
\pgfkeys@temptoks=\toks17

(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfkeysfiltered.c
ode.tex
\pgfkeys@tmptoks=\toks18
))
\pgf@x=\dimen105
\pgf@y=\dimen106
\pgf@xa=\dimen107
\pgf@ya=\dimen108
\pgf@xb=\dimen109
\pgf@yb=\dimen110
\pgf@xc=\dimen111
\pgf@yc=\dimen112
\w@pgf@writea=\write3
\r@pgf@reada=\read1
\c@pgf@counta=\count89
\c@pgf@countb=\count90
\c@pgf@countc=\count91
\c@pgf@countd=\count92

(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgf.cfg
File: pgf.cfg 2008/05/14  (rcs-revision 1.7)
)
Package pgfsys Info: Driver file for pgf: pgfsys-pdftex.def on input line 900.

(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsys-pdftex.d
ef
File: pgfsys-pdftex.def 2009/05/22  (rcs-revision 1.26)

(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsys-common-p
df.def
File: pgfsys-common-pdf.def 2008/05/19  (rcs-revision 1.10)
)))
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsyssoftpath.
code.tex
File: pgfsyssoftpath.code.tex 2008/07/18  (rcs-revision 1.7)
\pgfsyssoftpath@smallbuffer@items=\count93
\pgfsyssoftpath@bigbuffer@items=\count94
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsysprotocol.
code.tex
File: pgfsysprotocol.code.tex 2006/10/16  (rcs-revision 1.4)
)) (/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/xcolor/xcolor.sty
Package: xcolor 2007/01/21 v2.11 LaTeX color extensions (UK)

(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/latexconfig/color.cfg
File: color.cfg 2007/01/18 v1.5 color configuration of teTeX/TeXLive
)
Package xcolor Info: Driver file: pdftex.def on input line 225.
Package xcolor Info: Model `cmy' substituted by `cmy0' on input line 1337.
Package xcolor Info: Model `hsb' substituted by `rgb' on input line 1341.
Package xcolor Info: Model `RGB' extended on input line 1353.
Package xcolor Info: Model `HTML' substituted by `rgb' on input line 1355.
Package xcolor Info: Model `Hsb' substituted by `hsb' on input line 1356.
Package xcolor Info: Model `tHsb' substituted by `hsb' on input line 1357.
Package xcolor Info: Model `HSB' substituted by `hsb' on input line 1358.
Package xcolor Info: Model `Gray' substituted by `gray' on input line 1359.
Package xcolor Info: Model `wave' substituted by `hsb' on input line 1360.
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcore.code.tex
Package: pgfcore 2010/04/11 v2.10 (rcs-revision 1.7)
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmath.code.tex
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathcalc.code.tex
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathutil.code.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathparser.code.tex
\pgfmath@dimen=\dimen113
\pgfmath@count=\count95
\pgfmath@box=\box27
\pgfmath@toks=\toks19
\pgfmath@stack@operand=\toks20
\pgfmath@stack@operation=\toks21
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.code.
tex
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.basic
.code.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.trigo
nometric.code.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.rando
m.code.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.compa
rison.code.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.base.
code.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.round
.code.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.misc.
code.tex)))
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfloat.code.tex
\c@pgfmathroundto@lastzeros=\count96
))
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorepoints.co
de.tex
File: pgfcorepoints.code.tex 2010/04/09  (rcs-revision 1.20)
\pgf@picminx=\dimen114
\pgf@picmaxx=\dimen115
\pgf@picminy=\dimen116
\pgf@picmaxy=\dimen117
\pgf@pathminx=\dimen118
\pgf@pathmaxx=\dimen119
\pgf@pathminy=\dimen120
\pgf@pathmaxy=\dimen121
\pgf@xx=\dimen122
\pgf@xy=\dimen123
\pgf@yx=\dimen124
\pgf@yy=\dimen125
\pgf@zx=\dimen126
\pgf@zy=\dimen127
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorepathconst
ruct.code.tex
File: pgfcorepathconstruct.code.tex 2010/08/03  (rcs-revision 1.24)
\pgf@path@lastx=\dimen128
\pgf@path@lasty=\dimen129
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorepathusage
.code.tex
File: pgfcorepathusage.code.tex 2008/04/22  (rcs-revision 1.12)
\pgf@shorten@end@additional=\dimen130
\pgf@shorten@start@additional=\dimen131
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorescopes.co
de.tex
File: pgfcorescopes.code.tex 2010/09/08  (rcs-revision 1.34)
\pgfpic=\box28
\pgf@hbox=\box29
\pgf@layerbox@main=\box30
\pgf@picture@serial@count=\count97
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoregraphicst
ate.code.tex
File: pgfcoregraphicstate.code.tex 2008/04/22  (rcs-revision 1.9)
\pgflinewidth=\dimen132
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoretransform
ations.code.tex
File: pgfcoretransformations.code.tex 2009/06/10  (rcs-revision 1.11)
\pgf@pt@x=\dimen133
\pgf@pt@y=\dimen134
\pgf@pt@temp=\dimen135
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorequick.cod
e.tex
File: pgfcorequick.code.tex 2008/10/09  (rcs-revision 1.3)
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoreobjects.c
ode.tex
File: pgfcoreobjects.code.tex 2006/10/11  (rcs-revision 1.2)
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorepathproce
ssing.code.tex
File: pgfcorepathprocessing.code.tex 2008/10/09  (rcs-revision 1.8)
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorearrows.co
de.tex
File: pgfcorearrows.code.tex 2008/04/23  (rcs-revision 1.11)
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoreshade.cod
e.tex
File: pgfcoreshade.code.tex 2008/11/23  (rcs-revision 1.13)
\pgf@max=\dimen136
\pgf@sys@shading@range@num=\count98
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoreimage.cod
e.tex
File: pgfcoreimage.code.tex 2010/03/25  (rcs-revision 1.16)

(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoreexternal.
code.tex
File: pgfcoreexternal.code.tex 2010/09/01  (rcs-revision 1.17)
\pgfexternal@startupbox=\box31
))
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorelayers.co
de.tex
File: pgfcorelayers.code.tex 2010/08/27  (rcs-revision 1.2)
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoretranspare
ncy.code.tex
File: pgfcoretransparency.code.tex 2008/01/17  (rcs-revision 1.2)
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorepatterns.
code.tex
File: pgfcorepatterns.code.tex 2009/07/02  (rcs-revision 1.3)
)))
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/modules/pgfmoduleshapes.cod
e.tex
File: pgfmoduleshapes.code.tex 2010/09/09  (rcs-revision 1.13)
\pgfnodeparttextbox=\box32
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/modules/pgfmoduleplot.code.
tex
File: pgfmoduleplot.code.tex 2010/10/22  (rcs-revision 1.8)
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/compatibility/pgfcomp-version
-0-65.sty
Package: pgfcomp-version-0-65 2007/07/03 v2.10 (rcs-revision 1.7)
\pgf@nodesepstart=\dimen137
\pgf@nodesepend=\dimen138
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/compatibility/pgfcomp-version
-1-18.sty
Package: pgfcomp-version-1-18 2007/07/23 v2.10 (rcs-revision 1.1)
))
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/utilities/pgffor.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/utilities/pgfkeys.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfkeys.code.tex)
) (/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgffor.code.tex
Package: pgffor 2010/03/23 v2.10 (rcs-revision 1.18)
\pgffor@iter=\dimen139
\pgffor@skip=\dimen140
\pgffor@stack=\toks22
\pgffor@toks=\toks23
))
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/tikz.cod
e.tex
Package: tikz 2010/10/13 v2.10 (rcs-revision 1.76)

(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/libraries/pgflibraryplothan
dlers.code.tex
File: pgflibraryplothandlers.code.tex 2010/05/31 v2.10 (rcs-revision 1.15)
\pgf@plot@mark@count=\count99
\pgfplotmarksize=\dimen141
)
\tikz@lastx=\dimen142
\tikz@lasty=\dimen143
\tikz@lastxsaved=\dimen144
\tikz@lastysaved=\dimen145
\tikzleveldistance=\dimen146
\tikzsiblingdistance=\dimen147
\tikz@figbox=\box33
\tikz@tempbox=\box34
\tikztreelevel=\count100
\tikznumberofchildren=\count101
\tikznumberofcurrentchild=\count102
\tikz@fig@count=\count103

(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/modules/pgfmodulematrix.cod
e.tex
File: pgfmodulematrix.code.tex 2010/08/24  (rcs-revision 1.4)
\pgfmatrixcurrentrow=\count104
\pgfmatrixcurrentcolumn=\count105
\pgf@matrix@numberofcolumns=\count106
)
\tikz@expandcount=\count107

(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/librarie
s/tikzlibrarytopaths.code.tex
File: tikzlibrarytopaths.code.tex 2008/06/17 v2.10 (rcs-revision 1.2)
)))
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgfplots/pgfplots.code.tex
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgfplots/pgfplotscore.code.tex
\t@pgfplots@toka=\toks24
\t@pgfplots@tokb=\toks25
\t@pgfplots@tokc=\toks26
\pgfplots@tmpa=\dimen148
\c@pgfplots@coordindex=\count108
\c@pgfplots@scanlineindex=\count109

(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgfplots/sys/pgfplotssysgeneric
.code.tex))
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgfplots/libs/pgfplotslibrary.c
ode.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgfplots/oldpgfcompatib/pgfplot
soldpgfsupp_loader.code.tex
Package pgfplots: loading complementary code for your PGF version...

(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgfplots/oldpgfcompatib/pgfplot
soldpgfsupp_misc.code.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgfplots/oldpgfcompatib/pgfplot
soldpgfsupp_pgfkeys.code.tex
\pgfkeys@pathtoks=\toks27
\pgfkeys@temptoks=\toks28

(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgfplots/oldpgfcompatib/pgfplot
soldpgfsupp_pgfkeysfiltered.code.tex
\pgfkeys@tmptoks=\toks29
))
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgfplots/oldpgfcompatib/pgfplot
soldpgfsupp_pgfmathfloat.code.tex
\c@pgfmathroundto@lastzeros=\count110
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgfplots/oldpgfcompatib/pgfplot
soldpgfsupp_pgflibraryplothandlers.code.tex
File: pgflibraryplothandlers.code.tex 2012/09/11 v2.10 (rcs-revision 1.17)
\pgf@plot@mark@count=\count111
\pgfplotmarksize=\dimen149
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgfplots/oldpgfcompatib/pgfplot
soldpgfsupp_pgflibraryfpu.code.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgfplots/oldpgfcompatib/pgfplot
soldpgfsupp_pgfcorescopes.code.tex
File: pgfcorescopes.code.tex 2012/11/30  (rcs-revision 1.38)
\pgfpic=\box35
\pgf@hbox=\box36
\pgf@layerbox@main=\box37
\pgf@picture@serial@count=\count112
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgfplots/oldpgfcompatib/pgfplot
soldpgfsupp_pgfcorelayers.code.tex
File: pgfcorelayers.code.tex 2012/11/07  (rcs-revision 1.5)
))
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgfplots/util/pgfplotsutil.code
.tex
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgfplots/liststructure/pgfplots
liststructure.code.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgfplots/liststructure/pgfplots
liststructureext.code.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgfplots/liststructure/pgfplots
array.code.tex
\c@pgfplotsarray@tmp=\count113
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgfplots/liststructure/pgfplots
matrix.code.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgfplots/numtable/pgfplotstable
shared.code.tex
\c@pgfplotstable@counta=\count114
\t@pgfplotstable@a=\toks30
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgfplots/liststructure/pgfplots
deque.code.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgfplots/util/pgfplotsbinary.co
de.tex
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgfplots/util/pgfplotsbinary.da
ta.code.tex))
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgfplots/util/pgfplotsutil.verb
.code.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgfplots/libs/pgflibrarypgfplot
s.surfshading.code.tex
\c@pgfplotslibrarysurf@no=\count115

(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgfplots/sys/pgflibrarypgfplots
.surfshading.pgfsys-pdftex.def)))
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgfplots/util/pgfplotscolormap.
code.tex
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgfplots/util/pgfplotscolor.cod
e.tex))
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgfplots/pgfplotsstackedplots.c
ode.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgfplots/pgfplotsplothandlers.c
ode.tex
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgfplots/pgfplotsmeshplothandle
r.code.tex))
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgfplots/pgfplots.scaling.code.
tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgfplots/pgfplotscoordprocessin
g.code.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgfplots/pgfplotsticks.code.tex
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgfplots/pgfplots.paths.code.te
x)
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/librarie
s/tikzlibrarydecorations.code.tex
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/modules/pgfmoduledecoration
s.code.tex
\pgfdecoratedcompleteddistance=\dimen150
\pgfdecoratedremainingdistance=\dimen151
\pgfdecoratedinputsegmentcompleteddistance=\dimen152
\pgfdecoratedinputsegmentremainingdistance=\dimen153
\pgf@decorate@distancetomove=\dimen154
\pgf@decorate@repeatstate=\count116
\pgfdecorationsegmentamplitude=\dimen155
\pgfdecorationsegmentlength=\dimen156
)
\tikz@lib@dec@box=\box38
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/librarie
s/tikzlibrarydecorations.pathmorphing.code.tex
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/libraries/decorations/pgfli
brarydecorations.pathmorphing.code.tex))
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/librarie
s/tikzlibrarydecorations.pathreplacing.code.tex
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/libraries/decorations/pgfli
brarydecorations.pathreplacing.code.tex))
\pgfplots@numplots=\count117
\pgfplots@xmin@reg=\dimen157
\pgfplots@xmax@reg=\dimen158
\pgfplots@ymin@reg=\dimen159
\pgfplots@ymax@reg=\dimen160
\pgfplots@zmin@reg=\dimen161
\pgfplots@zmax@reg=\dimen162
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/librarie
s/tikzlibraryplotmarks.code.tex
File: tikzlibraryplotmarks.code.tex 2008/01/09 v2.10 (rcs-revision 1.1)

(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/libraries/pgflibraryplotmar
ks.code.tex
File: pgflibraryplotmarks.code.tex 2010/10/15 v2.10 (rcs-revision 1.12)
)))
\figureheight=\skip43
\figurewidth=\skip44

(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/frontendlayer/libraries/tikzl
ibraryexternal.code.tex
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/librarie
s/tikzexternalshared.code.tex
\tikzexternal@outfile=\write4
))
\openout3 = `Minimalbeispiel.auxlock'.

 (./Minimalbeispiel.aux)
\openout1 = `Minimalbeispiel.aux'.

LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OML/cmm/m/it on input line 13.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 13.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for T1/cmr/m/n on input line 13.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 13.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OT1/cmr/m/n on input line 13.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 13.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMS/cmsy/m/n on input line 13.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 13.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMX/cmex/m/n on input line 13.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 13.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for U/cmr/m/n on input line 13.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 13.

ABD: EveryShipout initializing macros
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/context/base/supp-pdf.mkii
[Loading MPS to PDF converter (version 2006.09.02).]
\scratchcounter=\count118
\scratchdimen=\dimen163
\scratchbox=\box39
\nofMPsegments=\count119
\nofMParguments=\count120
\everyMPshowfont=\toks31
\MPscratchCnt=\count121
\MPscratchDim=\dimen164
\MPnumerator=\count122
\makeMPintoPDFobject=\count123
\everyMPtoPDFconversion=\toks32
) (/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/pdftexcmds.sty
Package: pdftexcmds 2011/11/29 v0.20 Utility functions of pdfTeX for LuaTeX (HO
)

(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/ifluatex.sty
Package: ifluatex 2010/03/01 v1.3 Provides the ifluatex switch (HO)
Package ifluatex Info: LuaTeX not detected.
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/ifpdf.sty
Package: ifpdf 2011/01/30 v2.3 Provides the ifpdf switch (HO)
Package ifpdf Info: pdfTeX in PDF mo
```

Scrrenshot of my TexStido preferences window:
[image: My preferences]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Can you please add a minimal complete document that shows the issue?

Comment: I tried the example file, but I can't reproduce the issue. So it might be something wrong with the options to the TeXStudio builder command. Can you try from the terminal?

Comment: Don't use `nonstopmode` when trouble shooting. You want it to stop so that it will hopefully tell you where the problem is! Did you remember to create the empty sub-directory for the externalised images?

Comment: the folder exists...i tried without nonstop mode...doesnt give me an error message anymore but doesn't produce a file in my auto figs folder either...(see question...added details there)

Comment: as for trying to run the builder commands from the terminal ? I don't have any experience with that...never even messed with the builder commands in TexSTudio before. There is a good chance that I messed up that part. I'll add a screenshot of there preferences window to the main question.

Comment: I was looking for solution on this for a long time. Even if this post is rather old, I want to link the solution for the posterity:
http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/226553/75668