# Make doesn't find pdflatex when using tikz externalize

Tags: tikz-pgf, pdftex, tikz-external

In short, I am using tikz externalize. When compiling my main tex file with:

```
pdflatex --enable-write18 --extra-mem-bot=10000000 --synctex=1 lecture-notes.tex
```

it generates a make file. Then, when I try to run it with:

```
sudo make -f lecture-notes.makefile
```

I get this error:

```
pdflatex -shell-escape -halt-on-error -interaction=batchmode -jobname "lecture-notes-figure0" "\def\tikzexternalrealjob{lecture-notes}\input{lecture-notes}"
/bin/sh: 1: pdflatex: not found
lecture-notes.makefile:16: recipe for target 'lecture-notes-figure0.pdf' failed
make: *** [lecture-notes-figure0.pdf] Error 127
```

For some reason, make cannot find pdflatex. Interestingly, when I run the command in the console myself:

```
pdflatex -shell-escape -halt-on-error -interaction=batchmode -jobname "lecture-notes-figure0" "\def\tikzexternalrealjob{lecture-notes}\input{lecture-notes}"
```

it runs perfectly.

I tried the workaround suggested [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/226499/tikz-externalize-doesnt-find-pdflatex), but that didn't work for me.

Lastly, I want to mention that when I run the first recipe in the makefile myself, then comment it out, and finally run:

```
sudo make -f lecture-notes.makefile
```

I get the desired output.

Any ideas?

Edit: Here are the first few rows of the makefile (after that, it just repeats itself following the pattern seen below)

```
ALL_FIGURE_NAMES=$(shell cat lecture-notes.figlist)
ALL_FIGURES=$(ALL_FIGURE_NAMES:%=%.pdf)

allimages: $(ALL_FIGURES)
    @echo All images exist now. Use make -B to re-generate them.

FORCEREMAKE:

-include $(ALL_FIGURE_NAMES:%=%.dep)

%.dep:
    mkdir -p "$(dir $@)"
    touch "$@" # will be filled later.

lecture-notes-figure0.pdf: 
    pdflatex -shell-escape -halt-on-error -interaction=batchmode -jobname "lecture-notes-figure0" "\def\tikzexternalrealjob{lecture-notes}\input{lecture-notes}"

lecture-notes-figure0.pdf: lecture-notes-figure0.md5
externalized_figures/lecture-notes-figure1.pdf: 
    PATH=/usr/texbin:$PATH

externalized_figures/lecture-notes-figure1.pdf: externalized_figures/lecture-notes-figure1.md5
externalized_figures/lecture-notes-figure2.pdf: 
    PATH=/usr/texbin:$PATH

externalized_figures/lecture-notes-figure2.pdf: externalized_figures/lecture-notes-figure2.md5
```

Comment: you need to check you path for sudo but why run make under sudo if you can run pdflatex under your own account?

Comment: running `pdflatex --shell-escape` under sudo seems brave is that really needed?

Comment: Because then I get this weird error: `pdflatex -shell-escape -halt-on-error -interaction=batchmode -jobname "lecture-notes-figure0" "\def\tikzexternalrealjob{lecture-notes}\input{lecture-notes}"
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.141592653-2.6-1.40.22 (TeX Live 2021) (preloaded format=pdflatex)
 \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
lecture-notes.makefile:16: recipe for target 'lecture-notes-figure0.pdf' failed
make: *** [lecture-notes-figure0.pdf] Error 1`

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/927512/how-to-set-path-for-sudo-commands  but I would not use shell-escape and sudo unless I had vetted every single line of ever file used.

Comment: Note that the flag -shell-escape is generated by tikz externalize. What are your suggestions?

Comment: you need shell-escape for tikz externalize but I'd  not use that under sudo. That gives whatever tex file you include admin access to do anything on your entire machine.  That seems a high risk strategy just for a cosmetic convenience of not having to arrange the pre-generation of your tikz images. But basically you are getting an error in a makefile you haven't shown so it's hard to help.

Comment: Apologies, I have added the makefile in the edited version.