# pdflatex' is not recognized as an internal or external command when using externalize

Tags: pdftex, tikz-external, gnuplot

I have been using externalize to generate my pictures for some time now and recently I attempted to generate pictures with `lualatex` and `gnuplot` in order to generate contour plots. After I followed different procedures to get it right I started having issues with my compilation, while not using either of the lualatex or gnuplot, more specifically when I enable `externalize`.

The message that I get is:

`'pdflatex' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.`

Just a bit of background, while setting up gnuplot I have added the environment variables in the PATH but did not modify anything else.

As of now, and since the beginning, my pdflatex compiler commands are:

`"C:/Users/Augusto/AppData/Local/Programs/MiKTeX/miktex/bin/x64/pdflatex.exe" -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode -extra-mem-top=1000000000 -extra-mem-bot=1000000000 -shell-escape "testtt".tex`

and while using externalize it make sure to enable the `-enable-write18` as in the following piece of code.

```
\usetikzlibrary{external}
\tikzexternalize[
prefix=tikz/,
shell escape=-enable-write18
]
```

I only get this message when I have externalize enabled whereas it disappears when I disable it by using the `\tikzexternaldisable` command in the `preamble`.

Whenever I compile the tex file I get the error message followed by

```
! Package tikz Error: Sorry, the system call 'pdflatex -enable-write18 -halt-on
-error -interaction=batchmode -jobname "tikz/test" "\def\tikzexternalrealjob{te
sttt}\input{testtt}"' did NOT result in a usable output file 'tikz/test' (expec
ted one of .pdf:.jpg:.jpeg:.png:). Please verify that you have enabled system c
alls. For pdflatex, this is 'pdflatex -shell-escape'. Sometimes it is also name
d 'write 18' or something like that. Or maybe the command simply failed? Error 
messages can be found in 'tikz/test.log'. If you continue now, I'll try to type
set the picture.
```

As a guess, I tried to create a dummy tex file for a MWE and the issue persists. I have tried to look up for it and found some questions regarding externalize and this not recognized issue, such as [[1]](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/55489/pdflatex-is-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external-command-operable-progra) and [[2]](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/226499/tikz-externalize-doesnt-find-pdflatex).

I have checked my environment VARIABLES and the one related to miktex is the following (which I had never modified before).

[image: path related to miktex]

When adding the following code in [2](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/226499/tikz-externalize-doesnt-find-pdflatex), the PATH is actually empty, which seems weird to me..

```
\tikzset{external/system call={echo $PATH > test.log}}
```

[image: PATH generated from echo $PATH test.log]

Finally, my **MWE** is shown below.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}
\usetikzlibrary{external}
\tikzexternalize[
prefix=tikz/,
shell escape=-enable-write18
]
%\tikzexternaldisable
\tikzexternalenable



\begin{document}
    
    \tikzsetnextfilename{test}
    
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        
        \begin{axis}[xmin=0,xmax=50]
            
            \addplot[domain=0:50, samples=100] {x};
                
        \end{axis}      
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Hope someone can help me with this!

Comment: add `C:/Users/Augusto/AppData/Local/Programs/MiKTeX/miktex/bin/x64`  to your path so `pdflatex` works and you do not need `C:/Users/Augusto/AppData/Local/Programs/MiKTeX/miktex/bin/x64/pdflatex.exe`

Comment: oh, that solved. I just wonder what has made it change without me deliberately changing it..